# Cannot get .ajax to call my php script

Tags: php, jquery

for the life of me I cannot get my PHP file to be called using the ajax function. Here is my relevant HTML:

```
            $(document).ready( function(){
                    $("#generate").click(function(){
                            alert("Been clicked");
                            $.ajax({
                                    url: "filterScriptForMe.php",
                                    success: function(data){
                                    alert("response");
                                    }
                            });             
                    });
            });
```

Here is my PHP file, which I can run by calling separately, and will print to the error log/echo/create the necessary image no problem when run on it's own:

> ```
>     error_log("script has been called");
>             $hello = imagecreatefrompng("./images/stock.png");
>             $hello = imagecreatefrompng("./images/stock.png");
>             imagealphablending($hello,false);
>             imagesavealpha($hello,true);
>             $x=imagecolorallocatealpha($hello,0,0,0,127);
>             $color = imagecolorat($hello,350,500);
>
>             for($y=0;$y<512;$y++)
>             for($z=0;$z<597;$z++)
>             {
>             if($color!=imagecolorat($hello,$y,$z))
>             {
>                  imagesetpixel($hello,$y,$z,$x);
>             }
>             }
>             imagepng($hello,"done.png");
>             echo "done";
> ```

I am beginning to wonder if there is a problem on my server at this point. When run it will print the first alert saying "been clicked" but it does not seem to be running the php script as I get no output to my log files when clicking the button from the html file, as opposed to visiting the php directly in the broswer. Both the html and php are in the same directory, and I have double checked the names to make sure they are correct.

I know other jQuery functions are working on the page as well, as I've been successful in getting some jQueryUI elements to display and respond to manipulation using jQuery alone. Added to that the first alert seems to be firing, so I'm fairly sure the library/code is in there. I've tried going through with firebug, but it's a little beyond me when it starts getting deep into the library and I lose track of what's being done and why.

Any help that you can provide would be much appreciated, at least to get the PHP file called from the html page. Thanks!

Comment: PHP lets you indent code as well, you know...

Comment: What is the path you the html file and what is the path to the PHP script? Are they definitely in the same directory? You should supply an `error` event handler for the ajax object so you can inspect the error message. You should also use something like chrome dev tools to inspect the network request.

Comment: url: "filterScriptForMe.php" 
is expecting a file inside $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] (maybe public_html?)

Comment: You should check your network tab in your browser to see if the request finds the php-file and what status code you get back. To faster see what's going on you can use console.log("Been clicked"); and console.log(data); the second one being the response from the ajax call.

Comment: I found the error.


The button that was being clicked was in a form. As soon as I removed that the function began making the calls to PHP. Thanks for everyone who looked at this, hopefully this will help someone else down the road who can't get their ajax calls to run.


Tl;dr: Check your button tags in the html.

EDIT: Can't submit as an answer yet. Will come back in ~7hrs.